# Returning only chosen fields from GitHub API

Tags: java, json, github-api, resttemplate

I am playing around with GitHub API and I am wondering whether there is a way to limit the response size, because I want to return only a few fields instead of calling for the whole JSON.

I know that certain APIs have the possibility of limiting by the query, like adding ?fields=field1, field2, etc, but I am not able to do this for GitHub API.

For instance I would like to get only id, name, and private from https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb.

I am using Jackson and consume via RestTemplate.

--Edit--
My main aim is to limit the time of the response. Using plain GH api it works ~185ms, and I want to achieve at least 50ms. Is that even doable at all?

Comment: Take a look at the graphql api. The client is able to choose exactly what data is returned https://developer.github.com/v4/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been looking into this, but I am not even sure how I could start with it to limit the results in my REST app... Should I create everytime body of the request?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the REST api in combination with the graphql library. How must move completely to the graphql library. Calls with the graphql library are totaly different.

Here is german article graphql for beginners: https://www.heise.de/developer/artikel/Java-Anwendungen-mit-GraphQL-Teil-1-4205852.html.

Here is a example query: https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#example-query
So your query should look like this (in http post body):
{"query":"{repository(owner:"octokit", name:"octokit.rb"){ id  isPrivate name }}"}

Answer (score 0):

use the below GraphQL as you wish

first Import the below CURL to POSTMAN

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.github.com/graphql' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{}'
```

change the Body type to GraphQL

```
query{
  viewer {
    name
     repositories(last: 10) {
       nodes {
         name
         url
       }
     }
   }
}
```